# pgfplots fillbetween with multiple curves

Tags: pgfplots, intersections, fillbetween

I have a *TikZ* picture like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-0.5,xmax=3.5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=3.5
  ]
  \addplot[very thick,blue, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=A] {sqrt(x)}; 
  \addplot[very thick,yellow!70!red, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=B] {9-3*x}; 
  \addplot[very thick,red!90!teal, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=C] {3}; 
  \addplot[very thick,green!70!magenta, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=D] coordinates{(1/9,-6) (1/9,6)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: the above tikzpicture, rendered]

I’d like to fill the area enclosed by these four curves.

Similar questions have been answered using `pgfplots`’s `fillbetween` package, but it only seems to support filling between *two* curves. What are my options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here a workaround, you can divide your area on two parts: first between curve A and C, and the second between A and B and use `soft clip` to limit filling

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-0.5,xmax=3.5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=3.5
  ]
  \addplot[very thick,blue, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=A] {sqrt(x)}; 
  \addplot[very thick,yellow!70!red, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=B] {9-3*x}; 
  \addplot[very thick,red!90!teal, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=C] {3}; 
  \addplot[very thick,green!70!magenta, samples=300, domain=0:3, name path=D] coordinates{(1/9,-6) (1/9,6)};
  \addplot[gray!30] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=1/9:2}];
  \addplot[gray!30] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=2:2.5}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]