# How to Shade Area between Three lines in Tikz/PGF

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm only aware of how to shade area between two curves, Simply by specifying a path for each curve with the parameter : Name path=A, etc. so far it worked by specifying 2 paths and then using command

```
\addplot [gray!30] fill between [of = A and B, soft clip={domain=1:3}];
```

I Wish to Shade Area bounded between three Lines, so on attempting to specify a third path C the command gives me an error, the said region in question looks like this:

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516723/fill-space-between-three-draw-lines-with-arbitrary-intersection-points and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398630/how-to-shade-the-intersection-of-3-lines

Comment: If You want to follow the fill between method, make this in two steps;
1) from 1 to 2 for lines A and B;
2) grom 2 to 3 for lines C and B.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. After plotting the three line You know the intersection points A(1,2), B(2,0) and C(4,3). So add the line:

```
\fill[gray] (1,2)--(2,0)--(4,3)--cycle;
```

(Almost) full answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
        %
        \draw[gray!20,step=0.5cm] (-6.5,-2) grid (6.5,6.5);
        %
        \draw[->,thick] (-6.6,0) -- (6.6,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-2) -- (0,6.6) node[anchor=south]{$y$};
        %
        \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
        \foreach \y in {-2,-1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
        %
        \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
        \foreach \y in {-2,-1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
        
        \fill[gray] (1,2)--(2,0)--(4,3)--cycle;
        \clip (-6.5,-2) rectangle (6.5,6.5);
        \draw[cyan,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-6.5:6.5] (\x,{\x/3+5/3});
        \draw[cyan,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-6.5:6.5] (\x,{-2*\x+4});
        \draw[cyan,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-6.5:6.5] (\x,{3*\x/2-3});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

\end{document}

Output:

[image]