# Shading a part of a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the domain bounded by the hyperbola `x^2/2-y^2/4=1`, the parabola `y^2=2x`, and the lines `y=0`, `y=1`.

I have plotted all these curves, by using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
          [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
           xtick={100},ytick={100},
           no marks,axis equal,axis lines=middle,
           xmin=-9,xmax=8,ymin=-8,ymax=8,
           enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]

            \addplot[color=black, no markers,samples=1001, samples y=0, domain=-6:6, variable=t]( {sqrt(t^2+4)/sqrt(2)}, {t} );

            \addplot[color=black, no markers,samples=1001, samples y=0, domain=-6:6, variable=t]( {-sqrt(t^2+4)/sqrt(2)}, {t} );

            \addplot[color=black, no markers,samples=1001, samples y=0, domain=-4:4, variable=t]( {t^2/2}, {t} );

            \addplot[color=black, no markers,samples=1001, samples y=0, domain=-2:3, variable=t]( {t}, {0} );

            \addplot[color=black, no markers,samples=1001, samples y=0, domain=-7:7, variable=t]( {t}, {1} );

            \draw node[below left] at (0,0) {\scalebox{0.75}{$O$}};
            \draw node[above left] at (0,1) {\scalebox{0.75}{$1$}};
            \draw node[above] at (6,1) {\scalebox{0.75}{$y=1$}};
            \draw node[below] at (7,0) {\footnotesize{$y=0$}};
            \draw node[right] at (6.5,4.5) {\scalebox{0.75}{$y^2=2x$}};

            \draw node[right] at (2,-6.8) {\scalebox{0.75}{$x=\sqrt{y^2+4)/2}$}};
            \draw node[left] at (-2,-6.8) {\scalebox{0.75}{$x=-\sqrt{y^2+4)/2}$}};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I shade the desired domain, by using TikZ, in order to point it out ?

[image]

Comment: This question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164991/pgfplots-how-to-fill-bounded-area-under-a-curve-using-addplot-and-fill might help you with the `pgfplotslibrary` `fillbetween`.

Comment: Unrelated: You might have noticed that the time it takes to compile your code is noticeable. That is because of the number of samples you've used. Even for the curves, 1001 is far more than you need, 51 will do nicely I think. And how many samples are needed for the straight lines? 999 less than you currently have. Note also that you can append `node[..]{..}` at the end of an `\addplot`, so you don't need the separate `\draw node..` lines. See example at https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/4cd1f662c61b2ec07e72bae079d0a859

Comment: @Torbjorn I understand and indeed the time it takes to compile is pretty long. Thank you !

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344021/pgfplots-fillbetween-with-multiple-curves/344039

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A way of doing it with MetaPost (integrated in a LuaLaTeX program), in case it may be of interest. The key to obtain the desired domain is the `buildcycle` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
path absc, line, hyperb[], boundary;
% Macro creating a parametric path
vardef parafcn(expr tmin, tmax, tstep)(text f_t)(text g_t) =
    save t; t := tmin;
    (f_t, g_t) forever: hide(t := t + tstep) exitunless t <= tmax; 
        .. (f_t, g_t) 
    endfor
    if t - tstep < tmax: hide(t := tmax) .. (f_t, g_t) fi
enddef;
% Parameters
u = cm; xmin = -6; xmax = 7; ymax = -ymin = 5; 
tmax = -tmin = 2; tstep = .1;
beginfig(1);
    % lines   
    absc = (xmin*u, 0) -- (xmax*u, 0); line = u*(-4, 1) -- u*(4, 1);
    % Hyperbolas
    hyperb1 = parafcn(-1.5, 1.5, tstep)(sqrt2*cosh t)(2sinh t) scaled u;
    hyperb2 = hyperb1 reflectedabout (origin, (0, 1));
    hyperb3 = parafcn(-3.5, 3.5, tstep)(.5(t**2))(t) scaled u;
    % Domain and its delimiters 
    boundary = buildcycle(absc, hyperb1, line, hyperb3);
    fill boundary withcolor .8white;
    for i = 1 upto 3: draw hyperb[i]; endfor; 
    draw line; drawarrow absc; drawarrow (0, ymin*u) -- (0, ymax*u); 
    % Labels
    label.llft("$O$", origin); label.bot("$x$", (xmax*u, 0));
    label.lft("$y$", (0, ymax*u)); label.ulft("$1$", (0, u));
    label.top("$y=1$", point 1 of line); label.bot("$y = 0$", (4u, 0));
    label.bot("$x = \sqrt{(y^2+4)/2}$", point 0 of hyperb1);
    label.bot("$x = -\sqrt{(y^2+4)/2}$", point 0 of hyperb2);
    label.top("$y^2 = 2x$", point infinity of hyperb3);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Frank Pastor Amazing solution, thank you very much !

Answer (score 13):

It's a bit tricky and maybe there is a more elegant solution, but it seems to do what you want.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        axis equal,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-9, xmax=8, ymin=-8, ymax=8,
        enlargelimits={upper=0.1}
    ]

    \addplot[name path=c1, color=blue, no markers,%
        samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-6:6, variable=t]
        ( {sqrt(t^2+4)/sqrt(2)}, {t} );

    \addplot[name path=c2, color=black, no markers, %
        samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-6:6, variable=t]
        ( {-sqrt(t^2+4)/sqrt(2)}, {t} );

    \addplot[name path=c3, color=blue, no markers,%
        samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-4:4, variable=t]
        ( {t^2/2}, {t} );

    \addplot[name path=c4, color=blue, no markers,%
        samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-7:7, variable=t]
        ( {t}, {0} );

    \addplot[name path=c5, color=blue, no markers,
        samples=100, samples y=0, domain=-7:7, variable=t]
        ( {t}, {1} );

    \addplot [color=blue!30]%
        fill between [of=c3 and c1, soft clip={c5}];

    \addplot [color=white]%
        fill between [of=c3 and c1, soft clip={c4}];

      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is also elegant to me. Thank you very much !

Comment: Beautiful! I'd color path `c4` in black, since for the purposes of the problem, is the same `x-axis`.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\pscustom[fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none]{%
   \psplot[algebraic]{0}{0.5}{sqrt(2*x)}
   \psline(!2.5 sqrt 1)
   \psplot[algebraic]{2.5 sqrt}{2 sqrt 1.e-6 add}{sqrt(2*x^2-4)}
}
\psset{linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt,plotpoints=500}
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{-3}{3}{t^2/2 | t}
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{4}{20}{ sqrt(t/2) | sqrt(t-4)}
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{4}{20}{ -sqrt(t/2) | -sqrt(t-4)}
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{4}{20}{ sqrt(t/2) | -sqrt(t-4)}
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{4}{20}{ -sqrt(t/2) | sqrt(t-4)}
\rput*(3,-3.5){$x=\sqrt{(y^2+4)2}$}
\rput*(-3,-3.5){$x=-\sqrt{(y^2+4)2}$}
\psline(-4,1)(4,1)
\rput*(3.75,2.75){$y^2=2x$}
\rput*(3.75,1.3){$y=1$}
\rput*(3.75,0.4){$y=0$}  
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]