# Issue with a shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to shade the domain bounded by the parabolas `y=-x^2, y=x^2+1`, and the lines `x=-1, x=3`.

By using the answer of @Salim Bou here [pgfplots fillbetween with multiple curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344021/pgfplots-fillbetween-with-multiple-curves/344039), I've used the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
     [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=middle,xtick={30},ytick={30},no marks,axis equal,xmin=-2,xmax=4,ymin=-10,ymax=10,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]

     \addplot[no markers,thick,samples=1001, samples y=0,domain=-1:3,variable=x, name path=A]({ x },{ -x^2 });
     \addplot[no markers,thick,samples=1001, samples y=0,domain=-1:3,variable=x, name path=B]({ x },{ x^2+1 });

     \addplot[no markers,thick,samples=3, samples y=0,domain=-1:2,variable=t]({ -1 },{ t });
     \addplot[no markers,thick,samples=3, samples y=0,domain=-9:10,variable=t]({ 3 },{ t });

     \addplot[gray!30,opacity=0.6] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-1:3}];

     \node[above right] at (0,0) {\scalebox{0.5}{$O$}};
     \node[below left] at (-1,0) {\scalebox{0.5}{$-1$}};
     \node[below right] at (3,0) {\scalebox{0.5}{$3$}};

  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

But it seems that the command `\addplot[gray!30,opacity=0.6] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-1:3}]` doesn't have any effect at my example.

How can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but if you remove `samples=1001` form the definiton of A and B, it works. Seems that the limit is between 100 and 200; when it fails, it says: `Package pgf Warning: fill between skipped: the first input path is empty. on in
put line 28.`

Comment: Also if you remove the `soft clip` it works, whichever the number of samples. Puzzling...

Comment: please, privide complete small document -- mwe -- not only code snippet ...

Comment: Without checking it it sounds like the already reported bug https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/194.

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/139/ and will work out of the box with the next release (1.16) of pgfplots

Comment: Thank you for all answers ! With samples=101 is working well, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are waiting for the bug to be fixed, you can use `pgfplots` without `soft clip` macro:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
                        N/.style={font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    xlabel=$x$,    ylabel=$y$,
    xtick=\empty,  ytick=\empty,
    xmin=-2,  xmax=4,
    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    no marks,
    samples=101,
    domain=-1:3
    ]
 \addplot[thick,name path=A] {-x^2};
 \addplot[thick,name path=B] { x^2+1};

 \draw[thick] (axis cs:-1,-1) -- (axis cs:-1,2);
 \draw[thick] (axis cs: 3,-9) -- (axis cs:3,10);

 \addplot[gray!30,opacity=0.6] fill between[of=A and B];

 \node[N, above right=of {axis cs: 0,0}]  {$ 0$};
 \node[N, below  left=of {axis cs:-1,0}]  {$-1$};
 \node[N, below right=of {axis cs: 3,0}]  {$ 3$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

While you are waiting for the bug to be fixed, here's an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), which you can compile with `lualatex` (or adapt for plain MP, or the [GMP package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en)).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric u, s;
    u = 5mm;

    path xx, yy, pp, A, B, S;
    xx = (left--right) scaled 8u;
    yy = xx rotated 90;

    s = 1/8;
    pp = ( (-1,1) for x = s-1 step s until 3: -- (x,x**2) endfor ) scaled u;

    A = pp shifted (0,u);
    B = reverse pp reflectedabout(left, right);
    S = A -- B -- cycle;

    fill S withcolor 3/4 white;
    drawarrow xx withcolor 1/4 white;
    drawarrow yy withcolor 1/4 white;
    draw S;

    label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
    label.top("$y$", point 1 of yy);

    label.llft("$-1$", (-u,0));
    label.lrt("$3$", (3u,0));

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reason for the parentheses around the second `x` in `(x,(x)**2)`?

Comment: @FranckPastor Superstition :-)   Just to make sure we get `(-1)**2` instead of `-(1**2)`; but in fact MP's precedence rules don't make this error, so they are not necessary.