# Plot graphs, shade areas and lines with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

How could I do the following plot with Tikz:
[image]

I'm new on Latex (and Tikz), thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? **(1)** [pgfplots fillbetween with multiple curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344021/pgfplots-fillbetween-with-multiple-curves) or **(2)** https://pgfplots.net/fill-between-plots/. It is unclear which part of the picture you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this real quick:

[image: shading graphs]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem,multicol}
\tikzset{axline/.style={-stealth}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
        
            \draw[dotted]
                (-1,1) --++ (-60:1.5)
                (-1,1) --++ (120:2)
                (1,1) --++ (-120:1.5)
                (1,1) --++ (60:2);
            \fill[olive!50] (-1,1) to[out=-60,in=180] (0,0) to[out=0,in=-120] (1,1) --cycle;
            \draw[axline] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below right]{$k$};
            \draw[axline] (0,0) -- (0,3) node[above right]{$E$};
            \draw
                (-1,1) -- (1,1)
                (-1,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) node[below]{$-k_F$}
                (1,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) node[below]{$k_F$};
            \draw (-1.7,2) to[out=-45,in=120] (-1,1) to[out=-60,in=180] (0,0) to[out=0,in=-120] (1,1) to[out=60,in=-135] (1.7,2);

        \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]   
            \path (-1,1) node[left]{$-\nu_F^k$} --++ (-60:4) coordinate (1);
            \path (1,1) node[right]{$+\nu_F^k$}--++ (-120:4) coordinate (2);
                
            \fill[olive!50] (-1,1) --(1) -- (2) -- (1,1) --cycle;
            \draw[axline] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below right]{$k$};
            \draw[axline] (0,0) -- (0,3) node[above right]{$E$};
            \draw
                (-1,1) -- (1,1)
                (1) --++ (120:6) node[left]{$L$}
                (2) --++ (60:6) node[right]{$R$}
                (-1,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) node[below]{$-k_F$}
                (1,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) node[below]{$k_F$};
            
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Amazing how fast you are! I only managed to open an empty text file up to now :).